# Difference between su root and su -

Tags: linux, su

What is the difference between switch users in linux with:

```
su root
```

and

```
su -
```

Comment: man pages are your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`su root` (also can be written as `su`) does not spawn a login shell

`su -` does spawn a login shell.

nothing is sourced when using the first (eg. .bash_profile, .profile, etc.)